# In CodeIgniter, How to access the folder that's outside of application folder using site_url

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

Here I am using this code.

```
<?php require  site_url() . '../../public_html/wp-blog-header.php'; ?>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Instead of `site_url` have you tried giving the complete path? Something like `../../public_html .....`

Comment: Yes, But that's show me some error. 
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare site_url()

Comment: Can you provide me an example of what is your full path?

Comment: If you are loading view file then why not using `$this->load->view()`?

Comment: @DanishAli I think using this $this->load->view() i can only access files that's inside the application/view folder. But i want to access the file that's outside of the application folder.

Comment: Oh, I forgot this point. Provide the directory structure in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FCPATH.

```
$nameOfDirectory= FCPATH . "wp-blog-header.php";
```

The `FCPATH` constant is defined at the bottom of the `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php require('../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

That's the solution. 
Thanks to @Tejashwi Kalp Taru and @danish Ali